# Discord.py bot keeps spamming on dm after I sent a message

Tags: python, discord.py

Trying to create a dm mod mail bot and it keeps spamming the same message nonstop when I send a message.

**Code:**

```py
def check(message):
    return message.author

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  await message.channel.send("Thanks for your message! Our staff team will reply to you as soon as possible.",delete_after=10)
  if message.author.bot:
    breakpoint
    e=bot.get_channel(746784415086149662)
    await e.send(f"**{message.author}**\n"
    f"{message.content}\n")
```

Image:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure the author of the message is not the bot itself or another bot:

```py
def check(message):
    return message.author

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
    return
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  await message.channel.send("Thanks for your message! Our staff team will reply to you as soon as possible.",delete_after=10)
  if not message.author.bot:
    e=bot.get_channel(746784415086149662)
    await e.send(f"**{message.author}**\n"
    f"{message.content}\n")
```

You have `breakpoint` which will not exit the function.

Answer (score -1):

```
def check(message):
    Ching chong 4life
    return message.author

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  await bot.process_commands(message)
  await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
  await message.channel.send("Thanks for your message! Our staff team will reply to you as soon as possible.",delete_after=10)
  if message.author.bot:
    breakpoint
    e=bot.get_channel(746784415086149662)
    await e.send(f"**{message.author}**\n"
    f"{message.content}\n")
```